# Creating a user-configurable New Relic Plugin

Tags: newrelic-platform

I've been playing around with the New Relic Ruby SDK and created a proof-of-concept [plugin](https://github.com/gingerlime/graphite-newrelic) which gets data out of Graphite, and sends it to New Relic.

Other plugins I've seen target a well-known set of data (e.g. Apache Requests or CPU load). However, in this case I cannot pre-configure the dashboards for publishing, because the data for each user will be completely different, depending on how they configure it and the data they store on their graphite.

Is there a way to publish a plugin *without* a pre-configured dashboard / charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every New Relic published plugin necessarily includes a Dashboard. You could record metrics like "Component/Graphite/" and then expose the results generically in your associated dashboard with "Component/Graphite/*". Most likely those won't be very useful graphs.

If you treat this as a Graphite plugin SDK for users who want to easily collect Graphite metrics by configuration, it will make more sense. When doing this, you should make the [GUID](https://newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/the-parts-of-a-plugin#guid) configurable as well and include clear instructions on changing the GUID for each use of the SDK. That way, users will get their own fresh Dashboards each time their use your SDK.

Comment: Thanks. The current code pretty much works this way (as an SDK more than a plugin). But I was hoping for a way to publish this as a plugin. This way it's easier to find / know that this exists, yet still allows the end-user to tweak the dashboards to match their data and reporting requirements.

Comment: One option is to make some sensible default choices for your users as to metrics names and dashboard layout, then publish your plugin - that'd get it into Plugin Central. Then, in your plugin docs, you could show how users can customize your agent to report on other Graphite-resident metrics.

Comment: @Cooper - But that defeats the purpose of a customizable plugin (hence my question). You can't have sensible defaults for graphite data, because almost by definition it uses custom data. Each user will have a completely different set of metrics they are collecting.

Comment: @YoavAner consider this:
With the Graphite metrics:
com.example.Queue.requests.size
com.example.Queue.responses.size
com.example.Cache.lookups.hits
com.example.Cache.lookups.misses

If you were to create a config like this:
Gauges: com.example.Queue, com.example.Cache

which creates New Relic metrics:
Component/gauges/Queue/requests/size
Component/gauges/Queue/responses/size
Component/gauges/Cache/lookups/hits
Component/gauges/Cache/lookups/misses

You chart "Component/gauges/*" generically, but users could create "Component/gauges/Queue/*/size" & "Component/gauges/Cache/lookups/*" charts.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being daft, but other users of graphite who might be interested in displaying their data on New Relic, won't have `com.example.queue` or `com.example.cache` necessarily. They might have `widgets.sprockets.whatsits` and `foo.bar.baz` as metrics...

Answer (score 0):

Yoav, I strongly suggest you do not distribute your plugin agent with a GUID in place (you currently have com.gingerlime.graphite.graphite).

If another user runs your agent with their New Relic license key, and doesn't change the GUID, they will be unable to customize their plugin dashboards, and any customizing you do will not be seen by them.

In other words, un-published plugins should not be distributed publicly - anyone that uses a un-published plugin will have a bad experience (unless they first customize the GUID).

Comment: Thanks Cooper. I didn't realise this. I thought only the license key matters for customizations. I wonder how would the GUID have an effect if it's not a published plugin though?

Comment: If two different plugin agents, published or not, attempt to report to New Relic with the same GUID, strange things happen in the New Relic account for the 2nd and subsequent agents to report - these things are difficult to ascertain at a glance, and can only be fixed by New Relic Support.

Comment: seems very odd to me, and I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere, but I'll take your word for it. Thanks.

Comment: I made I typo - the first few words should read "If two different plugin agents that are not published attempt..." - multiple published plugin agents with the same GUID work just fine (as evidenced by Plugin Central ; ). This situation is documented here https://newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/known-platform-limitations#limitations